# get the hour of day from a query (DateTimeProperty)

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I need  to get the hour of day from query with DateTimeProperty field. But, I can´t find How to do.

```
class Products(db.Model): #Models.py
       created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)


prodd =  db.Query(Products).filter('__key__ =', keyproduc).get() #My query return .get()
dt=prodd.created # my datetimeproperty field.
```

I was try with "datetime.strptime", but that is not work.

Some Idea?

Regards.

Comment: the question, as written at 2012-03-31 03:24:48Z, shows: 1. no serious research effort, 2. no actual code from an attempt to solve the problem, 3. no error message from any such attempt. no personal offense intended; i've downvoted this question. if you fix one or more of the above issues by editing the question i will remove my downvote as soon as i can. please read the faq about how to ask a good question. thank you, and best of luck with your project

Comment: understood. I know about milli second. but, I written about strftime just for nothing really.

Comment: ok. does the answer by alberge help you at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That object is probably already a datetime object. Try this:

```
prodd.created.hour
```

You can also use `dir(prodd.created)` to find out what methods an object supports.

Full documentation on datetime objects:

http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects

Comment: Thats so easy. Searching on developers.google and nothing about it. TNX. hey, can You give link about this documentation?

Comment: @A3R Your search didn't give you any results because `datetime` objects are a part of the Python standard library - they're not specific to App Engine.